# Chebychev's inequality and binomial parameter $n$

Tags: probability-theory, random-variables, proof-explanation, expected-value, binomial-distribution

> We want $X$ to be a binomially distributed random variable $X\sim 
> \text{Bin}(n,p)$, where $p=2/27$. (Thus $\mathbb{E}(X)=\frac{2n}{27}$ and $\mathbb{V}(X)=\frac{50n}{27^2}$.) What is the smallest number of bernoulli repetitions $n$ that would allow us to use Chebychev's inequality (CI) to conclude that $P(X>0)\geq 0.25$?

Chebychev's inequality:
$$P(|X-\mathbb{E}(X)|\geq \epsilon)\leq \frac{\mathbb{V}(X)}{\epsilon^2}, \text{ where } \epsilon >0 \,.$$

**My approach:**

We can equivalently look at $P(X\leq 0)<0.75$ and realize
$$
P(X\leq 0)=P(\mathbb{E}(X)-X\geq \mathbb{E}(X))\leq P(|\mathbb{E}(X)-X|\geq \mathbb{E}(X)).
$$
The upper bound provided by CI yields the condition
$$
\frac{50n}{27^2\epsilon^2}<0.75\implies n<10.935\epsilon^2.
$$
In order to apply the CI at $P(X\leq 0)$ we have to consider $0<\epsilon\leq\mathbb{E}(X)$ because then

$$
P(X\leq 0)\leq P(|\mathbb{E}(X)-X|\geq \mathbb{E}(X))\leq P(|\mathbb{E}(X)-X|\geq \epsilon).
$$
So we get a second condition
$$
0<\epsilon\leq \mathbb{E}(X)=\frac{2n}{27}\implies \frac{27\cdot \epsilon}{2}\leq n.
$$
In order to find the minimum value of $n$ we have to consider possible $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that
$$
\frac{27\cdot \epsilon}{2}\leq n<10.935\epsilon^2.
$$
My conclusion is that $n=17$.

---

This approach feels a bit messy. Is it correct? Is there a more elegant approach using CI to obtain a lower bound on $n$? Maybe I can avoid the interval at the end of my proof or maybe there is some magic trick when applying CI to get a smaller $n$?

Answer (score 1):

Most of your solution seems to be correct and straightforward. You arrive at the correct answer, but the final step is a bit vague and hopefully I can help to make the reasoning clearer.

Logically speaking, I would like to say that $n$ has to be a fixed number, although unknown, before we can use Chebychev's inequality on the random variable $X$ having the parameter $n$! Let us regard $n$ as fixed for now; we can evaluate afterwards whether we "fixed the right $n$".

By rewriting the left hand side (I recommend drawing some intervals on the real line) Chebychev's inequality can be formulated

$$P(\{X\leq \mathbb{E}(X) - \epsilon\} \cup \{ X \geq \mathbb{E}(X) + \epsilon\} \leq \frac{\mathbb{V}(X)}{\epsilon^2}\,.$$

Since $X$ is nonnegative, $P(X\leq 0)= P(X=0)$, and so we want to be able to use CI to conclude

$$ P(X=0) \leq \frac{3}{4}\,.$$

You rightly note that in order to use CI to get an upper bound on $P(X=0)$ it is necessary to have $\epsilon\leq\mathbb{E}(X)$. While respecting this, we do want to have $\epsilon$ as large as possible to make the right hand side of Chebychev as small as possible. Therefore we choose $\epsilon = \mathbb{E}(X)$.

With $\epsilon = \mathbb{E}(X) = 2n/27$, CI implies

$$P(\{X = 0\} \cup \{ X \geq 2\mathbb{E}(X)\}) \leq \frac{25}{2n}\,.$$

Combining the above equation with

$$P(\{X=0\}) \leq P(\{X = 0\} \cup \{ X \geq 2\mathbb{E}(X)\})$$

we obtain

$$ P(X=0) \leq \frac{25}{2n}\,.$$

In order for the right hand side to be less than 3/4 we need $n\geq 17$ which gives the answer $n=17$.

---

Note that it is possible to calculate $P(X=0)$ directly by $\binom{n}{0}(1-p)^n$. This gives
$$P(X=0)\leq \frac{3}{4} \Longleftrightarrow \left(\frac{25}{27}\right)^n \leq \frac{3}{4}\,,$$

which holds true already for $n\geq 4$.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your answer correctly, but if $n$ is fixed then we can't estimate it anymore and it makes no sense to say that *"the largest possible $\epsilon$ will give the best estimate"*. Maybe you mean something else...

Comment: @Philipp Ah, I mean that Chebychev's inequality gives an estimate of a probability. We want this estimate to be as low as we can in order to be below 0.75. (The way the questions is stated we also talk about "estimating" $n$, but I think this might actually be a bit confusing. I'll think about proposing an edit to the question.)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion I am not a native English speaker. I thought that the question would make it clear that we are looking for the smallest $n$ such that $P(X>0)\geq 0.25$. It could be for example that it results in $P(X>0)=0.3$. No need to hit exactly $0.25$. The main focus is to shrink $n$ as much as possible.

Comment: No worries, I'm not native either, but I'd say that I've understood your question without trouble nontheless. I'll see if I can clarify things further in a bit.

Comment: I tried just now to reformulate the problem, but I see now that I unintentionally also changed the meaning. Sorry; I'll change it back, then I perhaps need to sleep on it.

Comment: @Philipp Now, hopefully, both the question and the answer are clearer. But I have to say that the question feels a bit unnatural, and perhaps it's best you check carefully that nothing got lost on the way from your untranslated original to my interpretation! Where did you get the question from?

Comment: Yes, you are absolutely right the question itself is very unnatural and lead to a lot of confusion in our class - but it was stated like this. I guess that the intention was to illustrate how poor the results of Chebychev's inequality can be. The question actually involves a first part where you are asked to calculate the exact number (which you did in the bottom part of your answer). One quick remark: You said that *"to make the right hand side of Chebychev as small as possible"*, it should rather be  something like "to shrink $n$ as much as possible".

Comment: @Philip Thanks for clarifying. I do really mean that we want to make the right hand side of Chebychev as small as possible. It's easily  possible to make the rhs greater than one, and then CI will tell us absolutely nothing! The smaller rhs the better. Remember in my suggested answer we start out by fixing $n$. Then we choose the best $\epsilon$ to minimize the rhs. In the end we allow ourselves to re-choose $n$.

Comment: As I mentioned before, it makes no sense to fix $n$. The result would just be an $\epsilon$ with the property that $\frac{\mathbb{V}(X)}{\epsilon^2}=\frac{50n}{27^2\epsilon^2}$ gets small. This tells us nothing about a minimal $n$. However, if you treat $n$ as a *variable* then by looking at $\frac{50n}{27^2\epsilon^2}$ you "see" that a large $\epsilon$ allows for a small $n$. This explains why we would want to choose $\epsilon=\mathbb{E}(X)$.

Comment: @Philipp It often does make sense to regard a parameter as fixed, even if we want to change or minimize it later. We can keep our cool and carry out preliminary calculations. Already when using CI the parameter is in some sense fixed. However, in CI, you are very free to choose whichever $\epsilon$ you want. So it is not correct that the result would be an $\epsilon$ with some certain property.

How can looking at $\frac{50n}{27^2\epsilon^2}$ tell us anything about any relationship between $\epsilon$ and $n$? Why couldn't we just have any $\epsilon$ and $n$ we wanted in this expression?